# VSTO Add-in Affecting Word's Compatibility Mode and Autosave Behavior

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I am developing a Word VSTO add-in. I noticed a strange behavior from the Word Application and I am suspecting my Add-in is the cause. After debugging the Add-in for some time, Word started showing **[Compatibility Mode]** on documents saved as docx files by the Add-in as shown in the figure below. This is not a document saved as 2010, 2007 or 2003 Word document but as my current version of Word which is 2016. The document is not supposed to open in compatibility mode.

[image]

And when I open Word, the Autosaved document that usually appears in a left pane suddenly starts opening completely with a yellow strip asking if the user wants to have it saved. And for the original document, the words **[last saved by user]** appears (in square brackets as typed and shown) at the end of the document title on the title bar.

[image]

[image]

I am suspecting my VSTO Add-in is tempering with the application to cause this behavior. My code is many and I can't say which part might be the culprit so I can post it with this question.

Does anyone have an idea or a hint of what is going on here please? Any information on how a VSTO Add-in could temper with normal Word Application behaviour can also be of great help in giving me some idea about where the issue might be coming from.

Edit:

This is how my Add-in saves the document:

```
document.SaveAs2(fullFilePath, FileFormat: WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments: false, Password: ref missing, AddToRecentFiles: true, WritePassword: ref missing, ReadOnlyRecommended: false, EmbedTrueTypeFonts: ref missing, SaveNativePictureFormat: ref missing, SaveFormsData: ref missing, SaveAsAOCELetter: ref missing, Encoding: ref missing, InsertLineBreaks: ref missing, AllowSubstitutions: false, LineEnding: ref missing, AddBiDiMarks: ref missing, CompatibilityMode: WdCompatibilityMode.wdCurrent);
```

I implement these callbacks whenever the Add-in starts:

```
Application.DocumentOpen += new Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentOpenEventHandler(WorkWithDocument);
            Application.DocumentBeforeClose += Application_DocumentBeforeClose;
            Application.DocumentChange += Application_DocumentChange;
            Application.DocumentBeforeSave += Application_DocumentBeforeSave;
            Application.DocumentBeforePrint += Application_DocumentBeforePrint;
            Application.WindowDeactivate += Application_WindowDeactivate;
            Application.WindowActivate += Application_WindowActivate;
            Application.DocumentOpen += Application_DocumentOpen;
            ((ApplicationEvents4_Event)this.Application).NewDocument += new ApplicationEvents4_NewDocumentEventHandler(WorkWithDocument);
```

I run these codes when a document opens:

```
Options options = this.Application.Options;
            if (!options.UseLocalUserInfo) options.UseLocalUserInfo = true;
            if (options.SaveNormalPrompt) options.SaveNormalPrompt = false;
            bool visibleHiddenText = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText;
            if (visibleHiddenText) Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = false;
```

This code is run before the document gets saved:

```
if (Doc.RemovePersonalInformation) Doc.RemovePersonalInformation = false;
```

The value returned from `Microsoft.Office.Interol.Word.Document. CompatibilityMode` is 15.

And in addition to all these, I run some codes to add a few custom styles and update some changes to the list galleries and link list levels to Heading Styles.

Comment: Provide an example of how you open, save and close document.

Comment: And which value returned from `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document.CompatibilityMode`?

Comment: @Auditive I've updated the questions to include the information you requested. Thanks.

Comment: Tried only `document.SaveAs(fullFilePath)` without other args?

Comment: @Auditive nope, I haven't tried that. Maybe I should test that and see what I get?

Comment: I've tested that simple save on files created with 2013 and 2016 Offices and no compatibility mode warn was showed.